# Anymote Library Update: Storing paired connection / pairing information

Tags: google-tv

@Megha Joshi,

do you know when you'll be updating the anymote library to remember paired connections? Im working on it since the whole weekend, but still without any success.

Another question which is crucial for my diploma thesis I am working on is: What might occur, that the stored connection does not work anymore. What makes the connection invalid?

Thanks,

Sebastian

Comment: I looked at the library and realized that it did not need updating. If the connection is established by a Service that runs for the lifetime of your application, than the connection won't be lost, unless there is a network issue. In which case the long running service can re-connect.

Comment: In my case I need a solution for a persistent stored connection. For my evaluation part, the STB needs to be preconfigured and then rolled out to several households over the world. Once the anymote pairing process has been fulfilled in preconfiguration, it is crucial that the pairing information is stored and can be used forever. Can this be done (guaranteed) with the anymote protocol?